# Updating cropped image data in mySQLi with jQuery, & Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have a form (that comes up in modal) where you can upload an image crop and resize it.  There are two buttons Cancel and Save & Crop.  When Save & Crop is clicked I have the following jQuery in `functions.js`:

```
/* handle functionality when click crop button  */
jQuery('#save_crop').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    params = {
        targetUrl: 'change_pic.php?action=save',
        action: 'save',
        x_axis: jQuery('#hdn-x1-axis').val(),
        y_axis: jQuery('#hdn-y1-axis').val(),
        x2_axis: jQuery('#hdn-x2-axis').val(),
        y2_axis: jQuery('#hdn-y2-axis').val(),
        thumb_width: jQuery('#hdn-thumb-width').val(),
        thumb_height:jQuery('#hdn-thumb-height').val()
    };
    saveCropImage(params);
});


/* Function to save crop images */
function saveCropImage(params) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: params['targetUrl'],
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            action: params['action'],
            id: jQuery('#hdn-profile-id').val(),
            t: 'ajax',
            w1: params['thumb_width'],
            x1: params['x_axis'],
            h1: params['thumb_height'],
            y1: params['y_axis'],
            x2: params['x2_axis'],
            y2: params['y2_axis'],
            image_name: jQuery('#image_name').val()
        },
        type: 'Post',
        success: function (response) {
            jQuery('#change_pic_modal').modal('hide');
            jQuery(".imgareaselect-border1,.imgareaselect-border2,.imgareaselect-border3,.imgareaselect-border4,.imgareaselect-border2,.imgareaselect-outer").css('display', 'none');
            jQuery("#profile_picture").attr('src', response);
            jQuery("#preview-profile-pic").html('');
            jQuery("#profile-pic").val();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('status Code:' + xhr.status + 'Error Message :' + thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

});

on `change_pic.php` I have the following:

First a switch statement:

```
/* Get post details */
$post = isset($_POST) ? $_POST: array();
switch($post['action']) {
    case 'save' :
        saveProfilePic();
        saveProfilePicTmp();
        break;
    default:
        changeProfilePic();
}
```

With the above I now have `case 'save':` This will then activate `saveProfilePic()` and `saveProfilePicTmp()`.  The latter works fine, the image is saved to the correct folder with sanitized name.  The other `saveProfilePic()` does nothing & I can't see why?  Here is function:

```
    /* Function to handle save profile pic */
function saveProfilePic(){
    include_once("config/config.php");
    $post = isset($_POST) ? $_POST: array();    
    //Handle profile picture update with MySQL update Query using $options array    
    if($post['username-id']){
        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".mysqli_escape_string($con, $post['username-id'])."'";     
        $resultset = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));      
        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultset)) {                     
            $sql_update = "UPDATE users set profile_pic='".mysqli_escape_string($con,$post['image_name'])."' WHERE username = '".mysqli_escape_string($con, $post['username-id'])."'";          
            mysqli_query($con, $sql_update) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
}
```

`($post['username-id'])` comes from the form as a hidden value & I need this to tie to the specific user.  Can anyone see why this wouldn't work?  Basically what happens on my form is the modal stays open and the cropped image area disappears.  The modal is suppose to close, but staying open I assume b/c `saveProfilePic();` is not executing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> ($post['username-id']) comes from the form as a hidden value

But you don't send that in your ajax anywhere (well, not labelled as `username-id` anyway). Your `data` object would need to include that, or you have to have it in a session:

```
data: {
    // Presumably  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv is the id?
    'username-id': jQuery('#hdn-profile-id').val(),
    action: params['action'],
    // If the above is a correct assumption, then you don't need this (or
    // just revise this key name from "id" to "username-id" like
    // I demonstrated)
    id: jQuery('#hdn-profile-id').val(),
    t: 'ajax',
    w1:params['thumb_width'],
    x1:params['x_axis'],
    h1:params['thumb_height'],
    y1:params['y_axis'],
    x2:params['x2_axis'],
    y2:params['y2_axis'],
    image_name :jQuery('#image_name').val()
},
```

If you don't want to change the above `data`, then change the PHP to look for `id` not `username-id`:

```
function saveProfilePic()
{
    # I would not do this, I would put the connection at the top of the page and
    # inject the $con into the function saveProfilePic($con)
    include_once("config/config.php");
    # I would check for !empty(), not isset() because it could be set, just empty
    $post = (!empty($_POST))? $_POST : array();    
    # Check for just id here not username-id
    if(!empty($post['id'])) {
        # You should be binding parameters, forget using the escaping stuff...
        $username_id = mysqli_escape_string($con, $post['id']);
        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username_id."'";     
        $resultset = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultset)) {
            # Again, bind parameters here, don't escape anymore
            $sql_update = "UPDATE users set profile_pic='".mysqli_escape_string($con,$post['image_name'])."' WHERE username = '".$username_id."'";          
            mysqli_query($con, $sql_update) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
}
```